# How to prevent multiple touch on Flutter Inkwell

Tags: dart, flutter, touch, hybrid-mobile-app

I new to flutter and i have a counter button that i want to prevent it from multiple touch.

The Tap Function is defined under `Inkwell` component (`onTap: () => counterBloc.doCount(context)`).

if i run this apps and doing multi touch, counter will go up quickly, but i dont want it happen. any idea ?

below are my code :

```
  Expanded(
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16),
    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
    child: InkWell(
      onTap: () => counterBloc.doCount(context),
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset("assets/images/home/tap.png", scale: 11,),
          StreamBuilder(
            initialData: 0,
            stream: counterBloc.counterStream,
            builder: (BuildContext ctx, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot){
              return Text("${snapshot.data}",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 120),);
            },
          ),
        ],
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use an `AbsorbPointer`

```
AbsorbPointer(
  absorbing: !enabled,
  child: InkWell(
    onTap: (){
      print('buttonClicked');
      setState(() {
        enabled = false;
      });
    },
    child: Container(
      width: 50.0,
      height: 50.0,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
  ),
),
```

and when you want to enable the button again, set the `enabled` to true, don't forget to wrap it with a `setState`

Answer (score 4):

Try this? It should solve your problem.

```
class SafeOnTap extends StatefulWidget {
  SafeOnTap({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    required this.onSafeTap,
    this.intervalMs = 500,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final Widget child;
  final GestureTapCallback onSafeTap;
  final int intervalMs;

  @override
  _SafeOnTapState createState() => _SafeOnTapState();
}

class _SafeOnTapState extends State<SafeOnTap> {
  int lastTimeClicked = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        final now = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
        if (now - lastTimeClicked < widget.intervalMs) {
          return;
        }
        lastTimeClicked = now;
        widget.onSafeTap();
      },
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

You can wrap any kind of widget if you want.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              // every click need to wait for 500ms
              SafeOnTap(
                onSafeTap: () => log('500ms'),
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 200,
                  child: Center(child: Text('500ms click me')),
                ),
              ),
              // every click need to wait for 2000ms
              SafeOnTap(
                intervalMs: 2000,
                onSafeTap: () => log('2000ms'),
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 200,
                  child: Center(child: Text('2000ms click me')),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use *debouncing* to prevent this kind of behaviour ie with [easy_debounce](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_debounce), or [implementing your own debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791501/how-to-debounce-textfield-onchange-in-dart).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [IgnorePointer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html)

```
IgnorePointer(
ignoring: !isEnabled
child: yourChildWidget
)
```

And when you disable the component, it starts ignoring the touches within the boundary of the widget.

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't rely on setState, I'd go with a simple solution like this:

```
Widget createMultiClickPreventedButton(String text, VoidCallback clickHandler) {
  var clicked = false;
  return ElevatedButton(
  child: Text(text),
  onPressed: () {
    if (!clicked) {
      clicked = true;
      clickHandler.call();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `Stream` to make counter to count only on debounced taps.

```
final BehaviourSubject onTapStream = BehaviourSubject()

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  // Debounce your taps here
  onTapStream.debounceTime(const Duration(milliseconds: 300)).listen((_) {
      
     // Do something on tap
     print(1);
  });
}
```