# Flutter optimize API number of calls in TextField autocomplete implementation

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to implement autocomplete for selecting places in my app. For that I use Here Maps API. At the moment I have this for a `TextField`:

```
onChanged: (query){
    print("Current value is: ${query}");
    if(query) { getPlacesFromHereMaps(query); } 
},
```

Here, each time user enters some letter Here autocomplete API is being called.

So, if user types "New York" that means app will call API for about 8 times which I find too much. Is there a way to optimize this?

Comment: a good solution is to use what's called a `debounce`. Basically, this waits for the user to stop typing for a certain amount of time before calling the api. please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791501/how-to-debounce-textfield-onchange-in-dart) for the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onChanged` is doing its job. According to docs:

> The text field calls the onChanged callback whenever the user changes
>   the text in the field. If the user indicates that they are done typing
>   in the field (e.g., by pressing a button on the soft keyboard), the
>   text field calls the onSubmitted callback.

If you want to optimize, you can do something like:

```
onChanged(query) {
  if (query.length < 2) return;
  // if the length of the word is less than 2, stop executing your API call.

  // rest of your code
  getPlacesFromHereMaps(query);

}
```

Comment: This not solves the problem, I found that using "Timer _debounce" works like a charm.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad how do you think it's solve OPs question ? just curious to know, your solution will call API almost everytime a user enters a character(except length <2) ?

Answer (score 4):

You can call the API whenever the user finshes typing a word or after every 3 (or 2) characters.

But don't forget to call the API when the user submits the query(using `onSubmitted`).

Solution Code:

```
onChanged: (query){
    print("Current value is: ${query}");
    if((query.length%3==0)||(query[query.length-1]==' ')) { getPlacesFromHereMaps(query); } 

onSubmitted: (query){
   getPlacesFromHereMaps(query);
 }
},
```

=========

Alternate Solution:

As per @Karim Elghamry 's advice and @CopsOnRoad 's concern you can even use debounce to improve your UX.

In your widget state declare a controller and timer:

```
final _searchQuery = new TextEditingController();
Timer _debounce;
```

Add a listener method:

```
_onSearchChanged() {
    if (_debounce?.isActive ?? false) _debounce.cancel();
    _debounce = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
        getPlacesFromHereMaps(query);
    });
}
```

Hook and un-hook the method to the controller:

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _searchQuery.addListener(_onSearchChanged);
}

@override
void dispose() {
    _searchQuery.removeListener(_onSearchChanged);
    _searchQuery.dispose();
    super.dispose();
}
```

In your build tree bind the controller to the TextField:

```
child: TextField(
        controller: _searchQuery,
        [...]
    )
```

Source:  [How to debounce Textfield onChange in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791501/how-to-debounce-textfield-onchange-in-dart)

Comment: `After every 3 chars` doesn't look clean, it actually makes the app look irresponsive.

Comment: That's entirely on the developer as to what he would prefer to give more priority to.

Comment: Maybe he can accept yours but think in terms of UX, what user thinks the app isn't responding.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a better solution. Thank you for your concern and  @Karim Elghamry 's advice.

Answer (score 0):

**Considering the popular node package '[debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debounce)', below is the simple implementation**

```
/// Implementation of well known 'Debounce' node package in Dart
class Debounce {
  final Function _function;
  final Duration _duration;
  Timer _timer;
  int _lastCompletionTime;

  Debounce(this._duration, this._function)
      : assert(_duration != null, "Duration can not be null"),
        assert(function != null, "Function can not be null");

  void schedule() {
    var now = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

    if (_timer == null || (_timer != null && !_timer.isActive)) {
      _lastCompletionTime = now + _duration.inMilliseconds;
      _timer = Timer(_duration, _function);
    } else {
      _timer?.cancel(); // doesn't throw exception if _timer is not active
      int wait = _lastCompletionTime - now; // this uses last wait time, so we need to wait only for calculated wait time
      _lastCompletionTime = now + wait;
      _timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: wait), _function);
    }
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

*1. Define*

```
var debounce = Debounce(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
  getPlacesFromHereMaps(query);
});
```

*2. Call every time when value changes*

```
onChanged: (query){
    print("Current value is: ${query}");
    if(query.trim().length > 3) { d.schedule(); }
}
```