# Filtering ListView, Delay Searching, Lookup, Debounce flutter and dart

Tags: flutter

I have a TextField where I type in a product code. After a few seconds, it should search for the code from the list and display the product that matches the code in the ListView.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debounce Textfield onChange in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791501/how-to-debounce-textfield-onchange-in-dart)

Answer (score 6):

Try with this.

```
    void main() {
    runApp(MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

    final Debouncer onSearchDebouncer =
        new Debouncer(delay: new Duration(milliseconds: 500));

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Center(
                child: TextField(
                    controller: this.controller,
                    onChanged: (val) => this.onSearchDebouncer.debounce(
                        () => print("text : " + val),
                        )),
            ),
            ),
        ),
        );
    }
    }
```

Custom `Debouncer` class with timer.

```
        import 'dart:async';
        import 'dart:ui';

        class Debouncer {
        Duration delay;
        Timer _timer;
        VoidCallback _callback;

        Debouncer({this.delay = const Duration(milliseconds: 500)});

        void debounce(VoidCallback callback) {
            this._callback = callback;

            this.cancel();
            _timer = new Timer(delay, this.flush);
        }

        void cancel() {
            if (_timer != null) {
            _timer.cancel();
            }
        }

        void flush() {
            this._callback();
            this.cancel();
        }
        }
```

Comment: What’s the benefit of your solution to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57207610/9842392), I usually use the other one and your solution is also interesting.

Comment: I have done with Timer and he as done with same but using Future, it is asyc class to handle background call. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html

Comment: Yes I got it, I don’t get it why I should do so.

Comment: thanks, but how can I add an empty listveiw at start?

Comment: @IanPerera not getting you, what you actually trying to archive?

Comment: so I have a product Code, I want to put that code in a search box, and the item display in the list builder. however I dont want to list to have any products showed, and i've see the search box filter through the products. I dont want that.