# How to catch speed typing on textField widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

This way called everytime the input changes. The problem is when user types fast, calling api every time and search result is changing always. (called google map autoComplete api)

How to call api when user stop typing? (Not close keyboard or onSaved)

```
TextField(
      decoration: _inputStyle(),
      cursorColor: Palette.defaultColor,
      controller: _textEditingController,
     onChanged: (value) => setState(() => _autocompletePlace(value)),
 )
```

Comment: use `debounce()` transform operator from https://pub.dev/packages/stream_transform

Comment: I think the better approach would be to cancel any previous API calls rather than relying on the user to stop typing.

Comment: are you using this for search?

Comment: @Salma.yes.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create [Debouncer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791501/how-to-debounce-textfield-onchange-in-dart), it would delay the execution of your code by chosen timer.

E.g. user enters '123' - the execution would be delayed by 200ms, user enters '4', last execution is canceled and another delay is created. If user does not enter new data for 200ms, `_autocompletePlace("1234")` is gonna be executed

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class Debouncer {
  final int milliseconds;
  VoidCallback action;
  Timer _timer;

  Debouncer({ this.milliseconds });

  run(VoidCallback action) {
    if (_timer != null) {
      _timer.cancel();
    }

    _timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds), action);
  }
}
```

```
final _debouncer = Debouncer(milliseconds: 200);
```

```
onTextChange(String text) {
  _debouncer.run(() => _autocompletePlace(value));
}
```

Comment: there is no need in reinventing the wheel: https://pub.dev/packages/stream_transform

Comment: This is not reinventing the wheel. It's simply using the Timer instead of streams

Comment: and `Stream`s are most likely the best way to follow in such cases - i could bet that for searching OP uses some kind of async method returning `Future` so its the best job for `Stream.asyncMap` method

Comment: @pskink can you give a exaple using `Stream.asyncMap`?

Comment: @BloodLoss there is some examples how to do it with streams over rxDart lib:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxdart/blob/master/example/flutter/github_search/lib/search_bloc.dart @pskink but I am also curious what do you mean by `Stream.asyncMap` :o