# afterTextChanged equivalent in flutter

Tags: flutter, textwatcher

I know we can use `onChanged()` or we can add listener to the `TextEditingController` to listen when we change the text in TextField from [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes). It will invoke when we start typing something. But I want to know is there any way that after text change (After stopped typing) listener in Flutter something similar to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher#afterTextChanged(android.text.Editable)).

Comment: but it will call when we start typing, I want to know how to listen when we stop typing.

Comment: Yeah, I want to do after stopped typing not on typing

Comment: after typing is different from on typing. There are two override methods in Text Watcher: 1.  afterTextChanged 2.  onTextChanged. I want afterTextChanged.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212128/discussion-between-shylendra-madda-and-pskink).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two other callback methods in the TextField class.

- [onSubmitted](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onSubmitted.html)
- [onEditingComplete](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onEditingComplete.html)

check them but If you want to do something when the user stopped typing there is no relative method for it. instead, you should use something like Debouncing. for using debounce you have several options like using a timer or using Streams and RxDart. check below links for complete example:

- [Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52930197/9689717)
- [Stream and Rx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54712919/9689717)