# Flutter delay with ignore further inputs

Tags: flutter

I would like to know if it's possible, say someone types something in the search bar and the onChange instance sends every time a request to the server. Is it possible to say the program should wait for 2 seconds? After this time it should query the server. The only thing that I know is Future.delay but the thing is. It only delays the request I think so.

thank you for your help guys.

Comment: You need to use Future.delay at the right place.

Comment: look for debounce. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791501/how-to-debounce-textfield-onchange-in-dart

Answer (score 1):

```
onChanged: (_) async {
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));

[Your function that triggers contact to the server]

};
```

It will pause for 2 seconds before making request to the server.

If you want user to press certain button that will make request to the server then user TextEditingController.

```
TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
TextFormField(
controller: _controller;
)
```

Now you can use _controller.text to get the input and use this text to make request to the server as a parameter.