# Flutter TextFormField call value change method after finish text input

Tags: flutter, dart

In my screen there are search features as per logic that's working fine but issue is I want to run my search function after stope typing??  So in the `TextFormField` there are `onChanged` method, how can we achieve it? I tried lots of ways like comparing `DateTime` but not able to achieved it.

~ PS : `onEditingComplete` method works perfect in my case but issues is, To call this method I have to click on return button, without click on return button is it possible?

Comment: please reference this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791501/how-to-debounce-textfield-onchange-in-dart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to create a debouncer, something like this.

```
class Debouncer {
  final int milliseconds;
  VoidCallback action;
  Timer _timer;

  Debouncer({this.milliseconds});

  run(VoidCallback action) {
    if (null != _timer) {
      _timer.cancel();
    }
    _timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds), action);
  }
}
```

Then initiate the object with your desired time of "after stop typing".

```
final _debouncer = Debouncer(milliseconds: 1000);
```

And use it in your onChanged method.

```
onChanged: (string) {
  _debouncer.run(() {
    //Perform your search
  }
);
```