# Flutter textfield - when and how save data to a remote server?

Tags: flutter, forms

I want to create a multiscreen / multipart form wizard, with each screen containing:

1. a question
2. several different controls (text, radio-buttons etc.) which allow him to answer the question

[image]

I want to save the state of the answers to a remote server.
For the radio buttons that's straight-forward (whenever the user changes it's value).

But what about text-fields?
I don't want to update the server with every character change, but on the other hand I don'w want to lose data if the user exit the screen or the app closes / goes to background...

What would be the best approach to save data from text-fields?
Can [Flutter's Form](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation) help me with that?

Comment: While using text fields you can use a Debounce Timer so you would only send requests after the user waits for certain seconds rather than typing all the stuff.

Comment: Good idea. is there a built-in Debounce mechanism in Flutter for that?
Also, I guess I should save when onSubmitted is triggered also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment suggests you can use a debouncer for that. Creating a debouncer is pretty easy:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class Debouncer {
  final int delay;
  late VoidCallback action;
  Timer? _timer;

  Debouncer({required this.delay});

  run(VoidCallback action) {
    if (_timer != null) {
      _timer?.cancel();
    }

    _timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: delay), action);
  }

  cancel() {
    _timer?.cancel();
  }
}
```

And to use it define it somewhere and then do:

```dart
yourDebouncer.run(() async {sendData(...)})
```

I suggest you send your data in the onchange method of your `TextField`. This way your user data is saved and your server will certainly not be overwhelmed. **Don't forget to cancel** the `Debouncer` in your `dispose` method.

```
@override
void dispose() {
  _d.cancel();
  yourDebouncer.dispose();
}
```

You might want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791501/how-to-debounce-textfield-onchange-in-dart) if you want more details on how to implement a `Debouncer`.

Comment: A Correct Demonstration!