# Debouncing button in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, button, debouncing

How can i prevent the users to accidentally press twice on the button thus placing the same order twice, using debouncing with timer?

I actually tried using debouncing on the button but I couldn't figure it out.
Can someone explain it to me how can I achieve this?

I made a Timer? _dobounce in my widget state,

I made a method

```
void _onButtonPressed() {
if(_debounce?.isActive ?? false) _debounce?.cancel();
_debounce = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 500),(){

});
```

}

I am sure this method is not how its supposed to be and I dont know how to use it.

Comment: You could set the `onPressed` property to `false` after the first click to disable the button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to debounce Textfield onChange in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791501/how-to-debounce-textfield-onchange-in-dart)

Comment: Yes and no, I cant figure it out how to use it on the onPressed.

Comment: It's best if you can disable the control by setting the action to null while the action is executing.  This requires triggering a setState or equivalent.  I'll have a video soon that shows that.

Answer (score 2):

You can create such a class for the debouncing mechanism using Dart's Timer class,

```
class DeBouncer {
  int? milliseconds;      // The delay time for debouncing in milliseconds
  VoidCallback? action;  // The action to be executed

  static Timer? timer;    // A static Timer instance to manage the debouncing

  static run(VoidCallback action) {
    if (null != timer) {
      timer!.cancel();   // Cancel any previous Timer instance
    }
    timer = Timer(
      const Duration(milliseconds: Duration.millisecondsPerSecond),
      action,            // Schedule the action after a delay
    );
  }
}
```

To use, wrap you method by DeBouncer.run method

```
      DeBouncer.run(() {
        /// Call Your method
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `Debouncer` class using `Timer`

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class Debouncer {
  final int milliseconds;
  Timer? _timer;

  Debouncer({required this.milliseconds});

  run(VoidCallback action) {
    _timer?.cancel();
    _timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds), action);
  }
}
```

Declare it

```
final _debouncer = Debouncer(milliseconds: 500);
```

and trigger it

```
onTextChange(String text) {
  _debouncer.run(() => print(text));
}
```